# why javafx application is not thread Safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am Confused about  Thread Concept in javafx.
So Help me why javafx application in not thread safe?
what is reason behind that?

Comment: Like almost all modern GUI frameworks, JavaFX is not thread safe by design, because adding thread safe code into EVERY aspect of the API is not only impossible, it's places a execution burden on the code (i.e. it makes it slower), instead, the burden is placed on the developer to know when and where they'd like to perform operations off the dispatching thread and to ensure that they properly synchronous that functionality with the UI

Answer (score 4):

From the [Concurrency in JavaFX docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm):

> The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface
>   of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be accessed
>   and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application
>   thread. **Implementing long-running tasks on the JavaFX Application
>   thread inevitably makes an application UI unresponsive.** A best
>   practice is to do these tasks on one or more background threads and
>   let the JavaFX Application thread process user events.

Comment: @MaulikPatel Yes you can !

Comment: See Platform.runLater() http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html

Comment: @MaulikPatel:- You are welcome. And if my answer helped you then do accept this as an answer!